# Light record details functionality

Tags: lightning-aura-components, detail-page

In LEX you are can now add different components to a record page.  One of those components is called 'Tabs' and Tabs allows me to display different things on the record page, for example I can add a Chatter Feed tab, an Activity tab or a Record Details tab.  I also noticed that I  am able to add more than one Record Details tabs which is what displays the record's page layout to our users.

So my question is can use this functionailty to display two different page layouts to the same user in LEX. Essentially, can I break my current page layout in half and display them in two different tabs

Answer (score 1):

You can't split the record detail into two tabs. You can add multiple record detail tabs but essentially you will be seeing same fields in both the tabs. 
[image]

From the above picture you can see that you can control page layout's to user's based on profile or record type.

**Note:** You can add multiple related list tabs with different related lists in each tab